# Java URL reader throwing IO Exception when reading special character

Tags: java, parsing, url, bufferedreader, ioexception

I'm having a problem reading the JSON of an URL, when the input has the character "é" (ALT130). The strange part is that the program works when launched from within the NetBeans IDE, but it doesn't when launched from the distribution jar. Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class URLReader {
private URL url;
private BufferedReader in;
private String inputLine;

public void getTextFromURL(String address) {
    try {
        url = new URL(address);
        GUI.textArea.append("url created\n");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8"));
        GUI.textArea.append("buffered reader created\n");
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            GUI.textArea.append(inputLine+"\n");
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        GUI.textArea.append("IO Exception");
    }
}
```

The output I get when the program is launched from within the NetBeans IDE is the following:

[image]

However when I launch the program from the dist jar, the output I get is this:

[image]

The URL object seems to be created fine, but the BufferedReader seems to throw an IOException. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you have it print out the full stacktrace? `ex.printStackTrace(System.out)`?

Comment: printStackTrace doesn't take any parameters

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, I did this: `} catch (IOException ex) {
            try {
                ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(new File("trace.txt")));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        }` but the text file comes out blank, with System.out nothing happens.